# this is written in python 3.3 and i''m getting error as syntax error. Can any one fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
while True:
    n=int(raw_input())
    if n!=42:
        print n
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Can you show us the traceback of the error?  (ie what the interpreter prints out when it tells you you have a syntax error)  That will help us help you figure your problem out.

Comment: Use code formatting and line breaks so we can actually see your syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Get a Python 3.X tutorial.  Python 3.X introduces non-backward-compatible changes to the language.  `raw_input` no longer exists and `print` is a function instead of a statement in Python 3.X:

Corrected code:

```
while True:
    n=int(input())
    if n!=42:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

[print is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) (not a statement) in Python3.  Use

```
print(n)
```

instead of

```
print n
```

Comment: That is a problem - but I would have thought the OP to have hit a `NameError` with `raw_input` first :)

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses around the parameter of a function: `print(n)` instead of `print n`